# In Banach Space, does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|Tx_n - \lambda x_n\| = 0$ imply $x_n$ converges? $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of unit vectors.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was working on something else and realized that my proof requires this to work.

Here is $T$ is a densely defined and closed linear operator. $\lambda$ is fixed. Intuitively I feel that it should be. I'd appreciate any hint as how I should proceed.

Comment: You need more assumptions, otherwise there are trivial counterexamples (e.g. $T$ has $\lambda$-eigenvector $v$, and $x_n=(-1)^nv$). Regardless, my instinct is that this is not true.

Comment: For a very simple counterexample, take $T = I$ and $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some condition that will make it true without changing the requirement on $x_n$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $T$ it is (vacuously) true.

Comment: Thanks. $\lambda$ is unfortunately in $\sigma_{app} (T)$.